# PHP modify previously echoed text

Tags: php, html, echo

Complete newbie to PHP, not quite sure how to handle this.

I have a hyperlink that I would like to modify the text of once it has been clicked.  So:

```
$linktext = '<a href="?foo=' . 1 . '">Click Me!"</a>';
echo $linktext;

if (isset($_GET["foo"])) {
  $linktext = "Click Me AGAIN!";
}
```

But this does not change the text of the original hyperlink.  If I add another `echo $linktext;` to the end, it just prints an additional hyperlink.  Is there any way to go back and modify the original text?

Comment: Use JavaScript, that's not how PHP works.

Comment: if doing using php, you need to put your `if (isset($_GET["bar"])) {` before the link, and also set the `Click Me!` to a var so it can be altered using a value set inside the `if`

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding the difference between server side and client side code: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'd hold the name of the line outside of it in a variable and include it.

This stops replication of the link section.

Something like this;

```
$link = 'Click Me!';
if (array_key_exists('foo', $_GET)) {
    $link = 'Click Again!';
}
$linktext = '<a href="?foo=bar">' . $link . '</a>';
echo $linktext;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to make the text dynamic by putting it in to a variable. By using the original code, I made the required modification:

```
$text = "Click Me";    

if (isset($_GET["foo"])) 
{
    $text = "Click Me AGAIN!";
}

$linktext = '<a href="?foo=bar">'.$text.'</a>'; 
echo $linktext;
```

Do observe that there now is a `$text` variable that holds the text and will be modified if `foo` has been set.